# How can I test Rails rescue_from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rescue

Rails 3 seems is ignoring my rescue_from handler so I cannot test my redirect below.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :rescue_404 

  def rescue_404
    flash[:notice] = "Error 404. The url <i>'#{env["vidibus-routing_error.request_uri"]}'</i> does not exist on this website."
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

In both functional and integration tests, this rescue_from is ignored, and the error is raised:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches "/non_existent_url"
    test/integration/custom_404_test.rb:5:in `test_404'
```

How can I make sure this is properly 'caught' in a test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3 handles `ActionController::RoutingError` in middleware, so `ApplicationController::rescue_from` doesn't see the exception. The Rails core team recommends using a catch-all route at the bottom of `routes.rb` ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/671)) until they decide on a fix.

One option is to use a catch-all route to handle routing errors then manually raise an exception to hit `rescue_from` ([code from my blog post about this issue](http://www.bdunagan.com/2012/04/27/rescue_from-routingerror-in-rails-3/)):

```
# routes.rb
match "*path", :to => "application#routing_error"

# application_controller.rb
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_not_found

def routing_error
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new(params[:path])
end

def render_not_found
  render :template => "misc/404"
end
```